# Downloading DLC Characters and All Star Mode

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I'm trying to do the challenge: Beat All Star mode on Hard with All of the Characters. If I download DLC characters before I finish, do I have to beat All Star with them too?

Furthermore, would that make the mode harder, since there would then be more characters? Or does the game compensate by making them easier to launch, or by giving you more healing items, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a note at the bottom of the [Challenges page](https://www.ssbwiki.com/List_of_challenges_(SSB4-Wii_U)) on the Smash Bros Wiki, the DLC characters (and Mii Fighters) are excluded from any of the challenges requiring 'all characters' to unlock, so buying them won't make it any harder to finish the board.

Answer (score -3):

If you are in the middle of playing the match when you download them then I believe that they will not be added, however if you start it after downloading them they will be added to the mode. That would indeed make it more difficult.